# Can I store the whole content of a required file in a JavaScript variable?

Tags: php, javascript

This seems like an odd problem. Maybe it's also the wrong approach. But I have to do this:

- there are a few menu items on a page
- the content for each page is stored in some `.phtml` files
- when the page loads the default content is displayed (using `require`)
- all other content should be loaded too and should be stored in a JavaScript-array
- when a user clicks a link, the content is swapped

The problem is:

- AJAX should not be used
- all content can't be appended in the beginning, for the good old SEO

All parts are easy, except for: How do I get the content into a JavaScript array. Something like `content.push('<?php print require 'page.phtml'; ?>');` won't work of course, because it will return a multi line string, which does not work with JavaScript. All ideas are welcome. Maybe I'm overlooking something very simple.

Comment: could you not include the second menu at the end of the page before the `</body>` tag in a hidden div, then swap menus over when needed?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought too in the beginning. But the problem is, as in the question, that than search engines will see the whole content of all pages in one page, which is not so good for the ranking (I've been told :) ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<script>
<?php

ob_start();
require 'page.phtml';
$contents = ob_get_clean();

echo "var content = ".json_encode($contents);
?>
</script>
```

if there is no php code in your `page.phtml` file you can make it even easier

```
<script>
<?php
echo "var content = ".json_encode(file_get_contents('page.phtml'));
?>
</script>
```

obviously you can use it in this way too:

```
echo "content.push(".json_encode($contents).");";
```

why not function

```
<?php
function json_require($filepath) {
  ob_start();
  require($filepath);
  return json_encode(ob_get_clean());
}
?>
...
content.push(<?=json_require('page_1.phtml');?>);
content.push(<?=json_require('page_2.phtml');?>);
content.push(<?=json_require('page_3.phtml');?>);
content.push(<?=json_require('page_4.phtml');?>);
```

Comment: i doubt that `page.phtml` is holding a php array or std object.

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski nice one but what if the page.phtml contents html string !! shouldnt it be like echo "var content = '".$contents."'";

Comment: @RupeshPatel [don't worry about that.](http://codepad.org/ZhXysWMa) - [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) is doing the job. JSON stands for "JavaScript Object Notation"

Answer (score 0):

you can use hidden divs than using js array, At the end of the your page so they wont effect the seo. Then use these divs id to swap your content.

I hope you are using jQuery if not this can be done even with simple js.

let me elaborate

```
<script>
function shouldBeCalledAtSomeEvent(page_id)
{
   var html = $('#'+page_id+').html();
   $('#idOfYourTargetElem').html(html)
}
</script>

<!-- end of your main file -->
<div style="display:none" id="page_1">
include('page_1.phtml');
</div>

<div style="display:none" id="page_2">
include('page_2.phtml');
</div>

<div style="display:none" id="page_3">
include('page_3.phtml');
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought too in the beginning. But the problem is, as in the question, that than search engines will see the whole content of all pages in one page, which is not so good for the ranking (I've been told :) ).

Comment: @insertusernamehere your better take care of usability of your website, then SEO. Using javascript is the worst thing because robots doesn't read scripts at all

Comment: @insertusernamehere yeh I havn't enough at SEO :)

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski Yeah, the idea was exactly, that the search engine should not read the content in the array. :)

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski don't worry I'm on it. Some Typo3 fixing was intervening …

Answer (score -1):

If you can't use ajax and you're worried about seo, I recommend you use a modified version of @rupesh answer: store the html in script tags so that they can be accessed by js and not be read by crawlers :

```
<script type="text/hidden-menu" class="hidden_menu" >
    include('page_1.phtml');
</script>
<script type="text/hidden-menu" class="hidden_menu" >
    include('page_2.phtml');
</script>
<script type="text/hidden-menu" class="hidden_menu" >
    include('page_3.phtml');
</script>
```

And then you can easily build your array in js :

```
var content = [],
    contentNodes = document.getElementsByClassName('hidden_menu'),
    i=0;
for(;i<contentNodes.length;i++)
   content.push(contentNodes[i].innerHTML);
```

And voila: you have your content array that holds the html sent from php without using ajax and without affecting seo.

Comment: If there will be `</script>` tag in .phtml file everything will colapse